# TypeScript: return type for method with variable structure

Tags: typescript

I have a method which accepts a array of properties of an object and returns an object with a given shape:

```js
// sample class
class T {
  propA: number;
  propB: string;

  method() {}

}


function myMethod(obj: any, properties: string[]): MyMethodReturnType {
   // implementation
}

const obj = new T();

const result = myMethod(obj, ['propA', 'propB'])

// result will be the following:
{
 propATrigger: NotRelevantType;
 propBTrigger: NotRelevantType;
}
```

--> So `myMethod` returns an object containing key-value pairs for all properties passed in the array of keys, postfixed with "Trigger"

My question is:
How would the return type `MyMethodReturnType`  of `myMethod` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4FkCmUAWcAmAPACqKYAeUmY+AzogEqYCG+CANqgIIBOPzqQrSg8YYAOYA+SQAo4AIwBWALkTMwqADSIADjzg7MPWJlqriASlUBvAFCIHiANp6DiMYmJOwIZPKMAumr0AAYAJNauOgC+xKLi4kYhAarycHDsLGC20Yh2jgD0Be7IOpnI1FDMsAj2DjzYIDxI1rnM9OqoOba2EAjCiA20IOxQiAC8KBjYePgyrdpOAORRXEvaK-o6AEJLQe2IfWDCFr39Y+QTg6YjUAB0q3EwCUZnx2OoV0O3D1vbTy8eG8BsBmDB2PRJt9Rr8DFwgA)):

```js
function myMethod<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(obj: any, properties: T): {
    [prop in T[number] as `${prop}Trigger`]: boolean
} {
   // implementation
   return {} as any
}

const result = myMethod({}, ['propA', 'propB'] as const)
const x = result.propATrigger
const y = result.propBTrigger
const fails = result.propA
```

With `{ [prop in T[number]]: any }` you can create an object with the keys of the array `T`. By using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) you can add `Trigger` to the end of these keys.